# Naming, declaring and defining delegates and events conventions

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

#### How do you name delegates, events and instance of events?

I use this:

```
delegate void OnSomethingHandler();
event OnSomethingHandler onSomething;
```

Is this an accepted way? Notice lower and upper cases

---

#### Where do you place delegates and events?

I usually put delegates in an a namespace best reflecting them:

```
mynamespace.Def.SomethingLike
{

}
mynamespace.Def.SomethingElseLike
{

}
```

---

#### Where do you define events?

I usually place them into the class that uses them.

I notice that a lot of people define delegates and events in the same class. How common is that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Everything you have looks pretty standard - the only thing I would change is that the event name would be `Something` rather than `onSomething`.  Following Microsofts convention you would end up with something more like this:

```
delegate void SomethingHandler();
event SomethingHandler Something;

protected void OnSomething()
{
    if (this.Something != null)
        this.Something();
}
```

And as a cool trick you can add an empty delegate to your `Something` event so that you don't have to check the event for null before you raise it:

```
delegate void SomethingHandler();
event SomethingHandler Something = delegate {};

protected void OnSomething()
{
    this.Something();
}
```

Comment: I'd consider including the SomethingEventArgs to your sample as that is part of the convention. Also, EventHandler<SomethingEventArgs> is more common post 2.0

Answer (score 23):

[MSDN on naming events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx):

> Events always refer to some action, either one that is happening or one that has occurred. Therefore, as with methods, events are named with verbs, and verb tense is used to indicate the time when the event is raised.
>
> √ **DO** name events with a verb or a verb phrase.
>
> Examples include `Clicked`, `Painting`, `DroppedDown`, and so on.
>
> √ **DO** give events names with a concept of before and after, using the present and past tenses.
>
> For example, a close event that is raised before a window is closed would be called `Closing`, and one that is raised after the window is closed would be called `Closed`.
>
> X **DO NOT** use "Before" or "After" prefixes or postfixes to indicate pre- and post-events. Use present and past tenses as just described.
>
> √ **DO** name event handlers (delegates used as types of events) with the "EventHandler" suffix, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```
> public delegate void ClickedEventHandler(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e);
> ```
>
> √ **DO** use two parameters named *sender* and *e* in event handlers.
>
> The sender parameter represents the object that raised the event. The sender parameter is typically of type `object`, even if it is possible to employ a more specific type.
>
> √ **DO** name event argument classes with the "EventArgs" suffix.

So, events should be named with a verb or verb phrase.  Instead of `OnSomething`, use `Something`, assuming that `Something` is actually a verb, like `Close`, `Click`, or `ManagedPiplelineAbandoning` and `ManagedPiplelineAbandoned`.

The delegate for an event should be named with the `EventHandler` suffix, giving `CloseEventHandler`, `ClickEventHandler`, `ManagedPiplelineAbandoningHandler`, etc.

For delegates that aren't related to an event, use a noun, like `EventProcessor` or `ItemRetriever`, while an instance of that delegate is a verb, like `processEvent` or `retrieveItem`.

The casing of your delegate reference should be camel, unless the reference is not private.  I can't think of a case where you'd have a non-private delegate field, though.

However, since it is suggested to use the conventional event handler signature (i.e. `object sender, EventArgs e)`), you should [use a generic event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182178.aspx) instead of defining your own.  That is, your event would be defined as something like this:

```
event EventHandler<SomethingEventArgs> Something;
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding on bdukes answer/summary and using an example I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable), here's my attempt:

```
//from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11541/The-Simplest-C-Events-Example-Imaginable
using System;
namespace wildert
{
    public class TimeOfTickEventArgs : EventArgs //<- custom event args
    {
        private DateTime TimeNow;
        public DateTime Time
        {
            set { TimeNow = value; }
            get { return this.TimeNow; }
        }
    }
    public class Metronome
    {
        public delegate void TickEventHandler(object sender, TimeOfTickEventArgs e); //I put the delegate declaration before the events
        public event TickEventHandler Ticked; //Ticked(i.e. after something occurred), or possibly Ticking(i.e. before)

        public void Start()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                if (Ticked != null){
                    TimeOfTickEventArgs tot = new TimeOfTickEventArgs();
                    tot.Time = DateTime.Now;
                    Ticked(this, tot); //<- publish the event
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Listener
    {
        public void Subscribe(Metronome m){
            m.Ticked += new Metronome.TickEventHandler(HeardIt);  //<- subscribe to the event
        }
        private void HeardIt(object sender, TimeOfTickEventArgs e){ //<- this is the event handler (note signature 'object sender, xxx e')
            System.Console.WriteLine("HEARD IT AT {0}",e.Time);
        }
    }
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Metronome m = new Metronome();
            Listener l = new Listener();
            l.Subscribe(m);
            m.Start();
        }
    }
}
```